# What is this grass that supports all weather types, doesn't invade and prevents bad plants from sprouting?

Tags: grass, identification

It apparently doesn't grow longer than on the photos, can support all types of weather, doesn't invade other parts of the garden and it seems to prevent "bad" plants from setting up there (bramble, etc.).

Does anyone know what is the name of this grass?

[image: grass around tree]

[image: grass in more open clearing]

Comment: Where are you located? I've seen something similar growing in North Texas, in parks, etc.

Comment: It looks like he's in Shanghai, China.

Comment: That's correct, China.

Comment: how does it smell? (Serious Question!) Might be lemon grass?

Comment: There is no smell and it's not lemon grass. It's the average grass you can find in any garden but with a darker and that grows in clumps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After having asked a few professionals, the plant appears to be [ophiopogon japonicus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiopogon_japonicus) or (细叶)麦冬 = (xi ye) maidong in Chinese

Thanks to Lisa for giving more popular names: "mondo grass" or "monkey grass"

Comment: Ah, so this is related to mondo grass.  Thanks for including that in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly Sedge (Cyperaceae family), which is very similar to grass. There is a good photo of it [here](http://www.aboutornamentalgrasses.com/sedge_grass.shtml) and detailed information [here](http://www.offwell.free-online.co.uk/grass_id/intro2.htm). If you can post a close-up, we may be able to identify the variety - or you may recognize the variety yourself [here](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=832&site=images&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sedge&btnG=Search&oq=sedge&aq=f&aqi=g6g-s1g3&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=4056l5874l0l6l6l1l0l0l0l269l1133l0.1.4l5).

Comment: Sorry this answer was wrong. The plant is definitely **ophiopogon japonicus** or (细叶)麦冬 = (xi ye) maidong in chinese